# Required to leave the UK

Tags: visas, uk, applications, student-visas

I recently withdrew from my course in the UK and was asked by the university compliance officer to leave the country within 60 days with my visa being cancelled. In the visa application process there is a section which states that were you ever deported, refused, required to leave etc. Does required to leave refer to me if I am applying for a new visa to go to the uk?

Answer (score 4):

Unlikely, since in your case your visa, of unknown type,   (**leave to enter**) was *shortened*, since the conditions on which it was issued longer apply (your withdrawal from the course).

The legal term for this would be **curtailment of leave**.

For the visa types:

- Tier 2 (or 5) Migrant, §323A (a)(i)(2) would apply

  - Tier 2 is a general work visa
  - Tier 5 is a temporary worker / Youth Mobility Scheme visa
- **Tier 4 Migrant**, §323A (a)(ii)(2) would apply

  - Tier 4 (General/Child) Student

---

> **[Curtailment of leave in relation to a Tier 2 Migrant, a Tier 5 Migrant or a Tier 4 Migrant](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal)**
> **323A**. In addition to the grounds specified in paragraph 323, the leave to enter or remain of a Tier 2 Migrant, a Tier 4 Migrant or a Tier 5 Migrant:
>
> (a) is to be **curtailed** if:
>
> - (i) in the case of a Tier 2 Migrant or a Tier 5 Migrant:
>
>   - (1) the migrant fails to commence, or
>   - (2) **the migrant ceases, or will cease, before the end date recorded on the Certificate of Sponsorship Checking Service**, the employment, volunteering, training or job shadowing (as the case may be) that the migrant has been sponsored to do.
> - (ii) in the case of a Tier 4 Migrant:
>
>   - (1) the migrant fails to commence studying with the sponsor, or
>   - (2) the sponsor has excluded or withdrawn the migrant, or **the migrant has withdrawn, from the course of studies**, or
>   - (2A) the migrant’s course of study has ceased, or will cease, before the end date recorded on the Certificate of Sponsorship Checking Service, or
>   - (3) the sponsor withdraws their sponsorship of a migrant on the doctorate extension scheme, or
>   - (4) the sponsor withdraws their sponsorship of a migrant who, having completed a pre-sessional course as provided in paragraph 120(b) (i) of Appendix A, does not have a knowledge of English equivalent to level B2 of the Council of Europe’s Common European Framework for Language Learning in all four components (reading, writing, speaking and listening) or above.
>
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Immigration Rules part 9: grounds for refusal - Immigration Rules - Guidance - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal)

Comment: As a university student, the OP would probably hold a Tier 4 visa https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/843003/T4_Migrant_Guidance_October_2019.pdf#page61 A Tier 2 is a general work visa; a Tier 5 is a temporary worker / Youth Mobility Scheme visa.

Comment: @Traveller Yes and the text used the word **studies**.

Comment: What does it mean for the leave to be curtailed?  Is OP accruing illegal presence immediately, or is there a grace period to leave the country?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It means the originally leave to enter period is being **brought forward** (shorten)  to an earlier end date. As the OP writes, he was given 60 days to leave. After the 60 days he would have overstayed.

Comment: so does required to leave apply to me, as I did not get any option with regard to curtailment in my application.

Comment: @Prajeet According to Interpretation https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-introduction *curtailment* in relation to a person’s leave to enter or remain in the UK, means “curtailing their leave such that they will have a shorter period of, or no, leave remaining”. There is no reference to it meaning required to leave. If you are concerned about it, you could answer ‘yes’ in the application, explain the background and that you were uncertain whether ‘required to leave’ applied to your visa curtailment or not. UKVI will have it on record anyway.

Comment: @Prajeet *curtailment* is **not** part of the deportation procedure. As long as you left before the 60 days (i.e. within the period of leave granted) there was no overstay.

Comment: thank you for clarifying my queries @Traveller